# Nested .json to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file that I want to convert to a Pandas Dataframe. I have tried the previous solutions but could not get it to work.

Here is a sample from the file:

```
    {"dateTime": "2022-08-18",
    "minutes": [
      {
        "value": 94.5,
        "minute": "2022-08-18T05:01:00"
      },
      {
        "value": 94.4,
        "minute": "2022-08-18T05:02:00"
      },
```

I dont' need the "dateTime" column, and I want to get to:

```
value   minute
94.5   2022-08-18 05:01:00
94.4   2022-08-18 05:02:00
```

I am unable to extract the "value" and "minute" to seperate columns. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `pd.DataFrame( your_dict['minutes'] )` give you?

Comment: it gives: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: I did read the other posts with this error code but wasnt able to get past it

Comment: You may want to write a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without knowing your data fully it is not possible to comment.

Comment: You should share a better sample, as @SomeDude suggests, that code makes the magic.

Answer (score 1):

I might be off here, as others have stated you haven't given code but can you try:

```
import json
f = open("your PATH")
js = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(js, 'minutes', ['dateTime'])
```

This will signal to pandas that "minutes" has nested values and it will dig into them.